# How to make trie store reincidence of a word in C

Tags: c, string-matching, trie

the current node of my trie stores a char and a position (which is the position in the text where the current word being read ends).

if I read a word "foo" in position 100 and another word "foo" in position 200, how can my node store this 2 ocurrences? Is there a fast way (with arrays or something even faster to implement) or I'll need to implement linked lists?

Comment: When the number of elements is unknown and a useless area is not used beforehand,
When using arrays, the procedure of extending arrays becomes disadvantageous as the number of elements increases. If random access is not necessary in such a case, the linked list is advantageous. When dealing with a small amount of data, neither is much different.(Arrays may be advantageous, but the actual time is insignificant)

Comment: neither is much different --> There is not much difference.

Comment: There is a good introduction to [**Trie -  Implementation strategies**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Implementation_strategies) at wikipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your trie node looks something like

```
struct trie_node {
    struct trie_node *next;
    strict trie_node *child;
    wchar_t           character;
    off_t             position;
};
```

You might use `size_t position;` instead if the data is always in memory, of course.

If we assume many prefixes do not map to a specific position (because they are not complete words), it might be useful to use a separate array for the positions, ie.

```
struct positions {
    size_t            count_max;
    size_t            count;
    off_t             position[];
};

struct trie_node {
    struct trie_node *next;
    struct trie_node *child;
    wchar_t           character;
    struct positions *position;
};
```

Character nodes that do not correspond to complete words, can have a NULL `position` member.  The `count_max` corresponds to the number of positions allocated for, and `count` corresponds to the current number of positions. The array can be reallocated and resized when necessary. This kind of array resizing is common in real-world applications; the overhead (of reallocation) is considered quite acceptable, especially compared to the alternatives.

---

Another interesting option would be to use a linear array to represent the words in the text in the order as they appear, with the `position` member in the trie node specifying the index of the first occurrence in the array. Each array entry would contain the index of the next occurrence, plus optionally a link back to the trie node:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct trie_node {
    struct trie_node  *next;
    struct trie_node  *child;
    wchar_t            character;
    size_t             index;     /* NO_INDEX if no occurrences */
    size_t             occurs;    /* Num of occurrences, optional */
    wchar_t            word[];    /* Optional, entire word */
};

/* When 'index' refers to 'none', use: */
#define  NO_INDEX  SIZE_MAX

struct occurrence {
    off_t              offset;
    size_t             next;
    struct trie_node  *node;    /* Optional */
};
```

A container structure would have the array, and the trie would hang off it:

```
struct text {
    size_t             count_max;
    size_t             count;
    struct occurrence *occurrences;
    struct trie_node  *trie;
};
```

Your functions would then take a pointer to a `struct text`.

The `occurrences` array in the `struct text` can be dynamically reallocated as needed. (This is also why the `first` member in the trie node is an *index to the array*, and not a pointer: if it was a pointer, we might have to go through the entire trie to update all nodes' pointers, when reallocating the array, otherwise.)

Note that because we use a `size_t` as an index to the array, `NO_INDEX` is the largest possible value, and `size_t` is an unsigned integer type, it is sufficient to check `if (i < count)` to verify that index `i` is valid.

Each trie node that corresponds to a full word has `index != NO_INDEX`, and the C99 flexible array member `word` initialized to the full word (including the trailing `L'\0'`). The `occurs` member would have the number of occurrences of the word, *if it is useful*. (There is no *need* for it, other than that we humans might be interested in the number of occurrences of each word.)

This scheme allows a direct access to the sequence of words in the text.

If the occurrences are in increasing offset in the array, one can use a binary search to find the word that is between specific offsets. Because each occurrence has a back link to the trie node, which contains the full word in the `word` member, it is easy to print out any word that occurs in the file, without having to scan through the entire trie.

I wrote this answer, because I wanted to show how combining two very different data structures in this manner, can open up very efficient methods of accessing the data.  I cannot say whether it is *useful*, because usefulness depends on the problem that is being solved.